# Iterating over list of dictionaries in 2 dimensional list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I don't understand why this list comprehension isn't correct. If I understand list comprehensions correctly, it should first iterate over the dictionaries in the list [dict1, dict2] and then over key-value pairs in each dictionary and return the values. Were am I wrong?

```
dict1 = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}
dict2 = {'c' : 2, 'd' : 3, 'e' : 4}
[value for key, value in d.items()
       for d in [dict1, dict2]]
```

It gives the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-e8d31c1fb24a> in <module>()
      1 dict1 = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}
      2 dict2 = {'c' : 2, 'd' : 3, 'e' : 4}
----> 3 [value for (key, value) in d.items() 
      4        for d in [dict1, dict2]]

NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

I would expect:

```
[1,2,3,2,3,4]
```

Comment: note you can iterate over `d.values()` instead of `d.items()` which just clutters your code, if you are only interested in values...

Comment: Also, if you are iterating over a sequence literal inside a list comprehension, may I advise to use tuples... it makes it more clear IMHO: `[val for d in (dict1,dict2) for val in d.values()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the nested for loop in your list-comprehension is reversed. In list-comprehension, the first for loop is the outer for loop which executes firstly, then the second for loop. So if you switch the order, it should just work fine:

```
[value for d in [dict1, dict2] for key, value in d.items()]

# [1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more readable way might be this

```
from itertools import chain

d = [{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, {'c' : 2, 'd' : 3, 'e' : 4}]
chain.from_iterable(map(dict.values, d))
```

> [3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3]

Map each `dict` to its values only and `chain` the result. The order is not the same, but you'd expect that.

Comment: Technically speaking, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the advantage of lambda function in Python:

```
map(lambda x: x[1], reduce(lambda x,y: x.items()+y.items(),  [dict1, dict2]))
```

This will give what you want.

Comment: What is the advantage of a `lambda` \ `map` function here? To me, it looks more cluttered than the equivalent comprehension. Furthermore, `map` with `lambda` is slower than a comprehension, and in this case, your `reduce` uses the inefficient `x.items() + y.items()`.